# Delete all objects in Django except last N (N is big, about 1000)

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

What is fastest way to delete all objects except last 1000?

I can do it slow way:

```
last_events = Event.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-created')[:1000].values_list('id', flat=True) 

Event.objects.filter(user=user).exclude(id__in=list(last_events)).delete()
```

But I wouldn't like to load such long query to my DB.

I thought I can't find ID of border element and delete all objects before that element:

```
last_events = Event.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-created')[:1000].last()
```

But got:
`TypeError: Cannot reverse a query once a slice has been taken.`

I've also tried:

```
last_events = Event.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-created')[:1000][-1]
```

But got:
`AssertionError: Negative indexing is not supported.`

Answer (score 0):

What you first tried is the correct way of doing it. Sometimes `delete()` might be slow. You can avoid its slowness if you don't care about the following:

- Django has to ensure cascade deleting functions properly, thus looking for foreign key references to your models
- Django has to handle pre and post-save signals for your models

If you are comfortable with these, you can use `_raw_delete()` starting from Django 1.5+. Since it's a private method, I don't really like to call these methods.

The second answer might be a raw SQL query such as:

```sql
delete from table_events 
where user_id={user_id} 
  and id not in (
    select id
    from table_events
    where user_id={user_id}
    order by created desc
    offset {N}
  )
```

Both ways should be considered wisely before using them. Relations and under the hood Django functionalities will be ineligible for you. You should take care of those concerns on your own.